# executing snmpd::FATAL: kernel too old

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

can anyone help me to resolve kernel dependency ? I have done net-snmp packaging  on  linux-3.0.2-generic and trying to make it work on below version.

```
uname –a
Linux manage 2.6.18.8-1 #3 Wed May 28 14:06:14 UTC 2008 i686 unknown
```

Snmp version : 5.7.2.rc1

```
/usr/sbin/chroot /var/snmp3/ /usr/local/sbin/snmpd -f –Le
FATAL: kernel too old

file /usr/local/sbin/snmpd
/usr/local/sbin/snmpd: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xacef27c048394ffb2cdef4999566e9aa32e5d2dd, not stripped
```

so... the file wants  2.6.24 and above version
Hw can I resolve this issue and make it to work on 2.6.18 ?  Should I make changes in snmpd.c  and recompile it ?  if yes than how to do this ? If not than what is the solution of it ?

Comment: It is working fine on :Linux manage 2.6.39.4-1smp #7 SMP Wed Sep 26 08:36:38 PDT 2012 i686 unknown

Answer (score 1):

Just recompiling should be sufficient.

The toolchain used to recompile needs to have a version of the kernel headers and C library that will work with this kernel.

Alternatively, you can switch to a newer kernel, which also has the advantage that it is easier to get security fixes.